# Border-radius breaks aesthetically when applied.. Bug?

Tags: html, css, button

I have a small form that has a button at the end.

Without border-radius it looks like this --> https://s29.postimg.org/3yw0js3qf/screenshot--2017-04-02-20-18-33.png

When I apply border-radius it looks like this --> https://s11.postimg.org/t25tmdsf7/screenshot--2017-04-02-20-19-12.png

I'm working on Chrome, Windows OS. I've tried using web-kit just in case, with the same results.. Has this ever happened to anyone else?

Here's that bit of code in case there's anything I haven't seen there:

```
HTML
<div id="boton">
    <button type="button" class="texto">INGRESAR</button>
</div>

CSS
#boton{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 2%;
}

#boton>button{
width: 20%;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain more detail about what you want on that button to be look like ?

Comment: @RidoanSalehNasution Hi! I would like the button to look like a default one (like in this image -->  https://s29.postimg.org/3yw0js3qf/screenshot--2017-04-02-20-18-33.png) but with rounded corners

Comment: i have answered yours below. Just scroll down to see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to replicate the default style with the border and background gradient:

```
border-radius: 4px;
border: 1px solid #AFAFAF;
background: linear-gradient(#E3E3E3, #F7F7F7);
```

see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1gxkyq9c/

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I'm going to do this! Thank you! :D I still wonder with it changes the style of the dafault one when one applies the border-radius (like, directly.. without having to code the gradient and stuff)... it's weird haha

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one bro. Just click the demo to see the result. Hope this answer yours.

```css
#boton {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

#boton > button {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #F8F9F9;
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="boton">
    <button type="button" class="texto">INGRESAR</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I actually wanted it to look exactly as the image provided (with gradient and all) Thanks anyway! :)